# Transparently play video on projector, initiated from second display

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, tablet

Current situation as follows:

1. DLP projector (WUXGA - 1920x1200) is connected to the HDMI port of the computer's graphics card and displays the main content (ie. movie)
2. Second screen (standard monitor or USB display or WiFi tablet) should be "control center" for the projector - I would like to see desktop on it, with icons etc. I'd like to start movie from this "control center" but movie should play on projector only - and all operations should be transparent and invisible on the projector.

Which direction should I follow to resolve it and make working setup?

Comment: Might be worth a read: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=213326 (OP is trying to do the same thing)

Comment: Also possibly related: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1157941

Comment: This may or may not help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/393833/secondary-display-for-video-playback-only

Comment: Thank you for pointing me, @AndroidDev, I will try these solutions.